# PHP order foreach by latest date out of 4 dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have entries with a name and 4 status that have a date and a description.

the table is similar to this:

```
name, 
date_cancelation, 
date_success, 
date_meeting, 
date_setup,
note_cancelation, 
note_success, 
note_meeting, 
note_setup
```

In my foreach loop i achieved to determine which of these 4 dates is the latest so i show in my list something like this:

```
1) John Doe - last status at 11.12.2016 - canceled
2) Mary Jane - last status at 02.01.2017 - meeting
3) Peter Meyer - last status at 10.12.2016 - canceled
```

for the dates i have 4 columns in sql

Now i wonder how i can sort this list by the latest date while the date is not a unique column.

I understood by searching for the solution that i should first sort the SQL by the date but as the dates are in 4 columns i´m lost how to to it :)

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the code i have and it gives me successful a list of People with their most recent state:

```html
$query = "SELECT abc__form_jobstate.id , 
`jobstate_applicant` , `jobstate_jobstate` , 
`applicant__personid` , `applicant_name` ,      `status_success_date` , `status_cancel_date` , `status_meeting_date` , `status_application_date`, 
`success_note` , `cancel_note` , `meeting_note` , `application_note`
FROM `abc__form_jobstate`
LEFT JOIN abc__form_applicant ON ( applicant__personid = abc__form_applicant.id )
WHERE `applicant_jobangebot` =" . $di . „;

$db->setQuery($query);
$output = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($output as $outputs)  {

// set variables for dates

$vm_date = $outputs->status_success_date;
$ab_date = $outputs->status_cancel_date;
$pa_date = $outputs->status_meeting_date;
$ll_date = $outputs->status_application_date;

// set variables for notes

$vm_note = $outputs->success_note;
$ab_note = $outputs->cancel_note;
$pa_note = $outputs->meeting_note;
$ll_note = $outputs->application_note;

// put the dates into an array
$statusdates = [
  „Success“ => $vm_date,
  „Cancel“ => $ab_date,
  „Work“ => $pa_date,
  „Application“ => $ll_date
   ];

// See what date is the most recent inside the record

$max = max(array_map('strtotime', $statusdates));
$recent_status = date('d.m.Y', $max);
$recent_statustype = array_search(max($statusdates),$statusdates);

if ($recent_statustype== „Success“) {
  $statusnote = $vm_note;
  };

if ($recent_statustype== „Cancel“) {
  $statusnote = $ab_note;
  };

if ($recent_statustype== „Work“) {
  $statusnote = $pa_note;
  };

if ($recent_statustype == „Application“) {
  $statusnote = $ll_note;
  };


echo '<div class="col-lg-5“><strong>' . $recent_statustype . '</strong> at ' . $recent_status . '<br>' . $statusnote . '</div>';

}
    ?>
```

It´s like the list above

- 1) John Doe - last status at 11.12.2016 - canceled
- 2) Mary Jane - last status at 02.01.2017 - meeting
- 3) Peter Meyer - last status at 10.12.2016 - canceled

Now i would need to sort the list itself by the dates (Mary Jane would be at the top in this case) - But the date comes from different columns.

Hope i could better explain better what i struggle with. Thank you all!!!

Comment: just show your tried query and sample data. so we can help you

Comment: can you add to your post a "desc" from tables with dates ? maybe we can do it with mysql only :)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: check out `GREATEST` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: Why can't you just get SQL to do the sorting for you?

Comment: I don´t know, the dates come from different columns,... so no idea how to sort by 4 different columns. Could be that for one the cancel date is the highest and for the other one the Success date.

Answer (score 4):

Create column named `date` and set it's type to `date` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and then add data to this `table`. While fetching sort data by this column by applying query ORDER BY `date` desc/asc.

Comment: **ORDERED BY** -> **ORDER BY**

Comment: And also: It's-> its ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of uasort http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
uasort($array, function($a , $b){
        $aLatestTimeStamp = $a->getLatestTimeStamp();
        $bLatestTimeStampt = $b->getLatestTimeStamp();
            if ($aLatestTimeStamp == $bLatestTimeStampt) {
                return 0;
            }
            if ($aLatestTimeStamp < $bLatestTimeStampt) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
    });
```